# create flat list from coins and quantities

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have an array with coins, e.g. (`coins=[10, 50, 100]`) and an array of the quantities of each coin (e.g. `quantity=[1, 2, 1]`). I want to generate a new list `l`, which shows all coins I have (e.g `l=[10, 50, 50, 100]`).

So far i have this, which does the trick:

```
coins=[i for s in [b*[a] for a,b in zip(coins,quantity)] for i in s]
```

Is there a better way to solve this in python, than to create a list of lists and then flatten it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leverage itertools chain and repeat:

```
from itertools import repeat,chain

coins=[10, 50, 100]
quantity=[1, 2, 1]

result = list(chain.from_iterable(map(repeat, coins, quantity))) # thx @ miradulo

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[10, 50, 50, 100]
```

Advantage: it does not build interal lists that then get flattened but generates the values as iterables.

Comment: This implementation is actually similar to my suggestion of calling `Counter.elements()` https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/018e1b7aad8d1a33ee14aae5c466d581d31e2369/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L596

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the final order is not important, you could use a `collections.Counter()`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(dict(zip(coins, quantity)))
>>> list(c.elements())
[10, 100, 50, 50]
>>> c
Counter({50: 2, 10: 1, 100: 1})
```

Comment: did not use Counter.elements() yet, nice.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sum` to add the lists together:

```
L = sum(([c] * q for c, q in zip(coins, quantity)), [])
```

`numpy` also has a function that does exactly what you need:

```
numpy.repeat(coins, quantity)
```

EDIT: as @Chris_Rands points out `sum` is not optimal for long lists of lists. It seems to be the fastest solution for `quantity=[100, 200, 100]` but for `quantity=[1000, 2000, 1000]` `numpy` is much faster. Both are faster than the OP solution.

Comment: You could, but you should not https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Answer (score 0):

what i can figure out is :

```
for i in range(len(quantity)):
    for j in range(quantity[i]):
        print(coins[i])
```